# OpenGL sphere camera: cube rendering incorrectly

Tags: c, opengl

I implement a simple sphere camera by using OpenGL and I render a cube for observasion. But the cube is not displayed correctly. Like this:

[image]

Some surfaces of the cube are invisible, some are not. Can someone solve the problem? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <gl/glut.h>

#define MAX_EPSILON_ERROR 10.0f
#define THRESHOLD          0.30f
#define REFRESH_DELAY     10 //ms
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// constants
const unsigned int window_width  = 512;
const unsigned int window_height = 512;

// mouse controls
int mouse_old_x, mouse_old_y;
int mouse_buttons = 0;
float rotate_x = 0.0, rotate_y = 0.0;
float translate_z = -3.0;

// Auto-Verification Code
int fpsCount = 0;        // FPS count for averaging
int fpsLimit = 1;        // FPS limit for sampling
int g_Index = 0;
float avgFPS = 0.0f;
unsigned int frameCount = 0;
unsigned int g_TotalErrors = 0;
bool g_bQAReadback = false;

int *pArgc = NULL;
char **pArgv = NULL;

#define MAX(a,b) ((a > b) ? a : b)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// declaration, forward
void cleanup();

// GL functionality
bool initGL(int *argc, char **argv);

// rendering callbacks
void display();
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
void motion(int x, int y);
void timerEvent(int value);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // First initialize OpenGL context
    if (false == initGL(&argc, argv))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // register callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);

    // start rendering mainloop
    glutMainLoop();
    atexit(cleanup);
    return 0;
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Initialize GL
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool initGL(int *argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
    glutCreateWindow("Cuda GL Interop (VBO)");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glutTimerFunc(REFRESH_DELAY, timerEvent,0);

    //// initialize necessary OpenGL extensions
    //glewInit();

    //if (! glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_2_0 "))
    //{
    //  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Support for necessary OpenGL extensions missing.");
    //  fflush(stderr);
    //  return false;
    //}

    // default initialization
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);

    // projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat)window_width / (GLfloat) window_height, 2, 10.0);

//  SDK_CHECK_ERROR_GL();

    return true;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Display callback
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set view matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, translate_z);
    glRotatef(rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);            // 颜色改成绿色
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的右上顶点 (顶面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的左上顶点 (顶面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的左下顶点 (顶面)
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的右下顶点 (顶面)

        glColor3f(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f);              // 颜色改成橙色
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的右上顶点(底面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的左上顶点(底面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的左下顶点(底面)
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的右下顶点(底面)

        glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);              // 颜色改成红色
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的右上顶点(前面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的左上顶点(前面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的左下顶点(前面)
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的右下顶点(前面)

        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);              // 颜色改成黄色
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的右上顶点(后面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的左上顶点(后面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的左下顶点(后面)
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的右下顶点(后面)

        glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);              // 颜色改成蓝色
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的右上顶点(左面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的左上顶点(左面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的左下顶点(左面)
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的右下顶点(左面)

        glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);              // 颜色改成紫罗兰色
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的右上顶点(右面)
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的左上顶点(右面)
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f);          // 四边形的左下顶点(右面)
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f);          // 四边形的右下顶点(右面)
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timerEvent(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(REFRESH_DELAY, timerEvent,0);
}

void cleanup()
{
    //sdkDeleteTimer(&timer);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Keyboard events handler
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int /*x*/, int /*y*/)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case (27) :
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Mouse event handlers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouse_buttons |= 1<<button;
    }
    else if (state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        mouse_buttons = 0;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    float dx, dy;
    dx = (float)(x - mouse_old_x);
    dy = (float)(y - mouse_old_y);

    if (mouse_buttons & 1)
    {
        rotate_x += dy * 0.2f;
        rotate_y += dx * 0.2f;
    }
    else if (mouse_buttons & 4)
    {
        translate_z += dy * 0.01f;
    }

    mouse_old_x = x;
    mouse_old_y = y;
}
```

Left click for rotation, and right click to change the radius.

Comment: Are you sure you have the vertex winding correct? IME the biggest culprit in OpenGL of "stuff not showing up for no good reason" is when you don't have the vertices listed counterclockwise with respect to the camera facing the front of the polygon. My brain begins to overflow when reading too many 3-dimensional vertex coords though so I'm not verifying it myself. Just an idea.

Comment: What is a "sphere camera"? You appear to be simply doing translations in z and rotations in x/y.

Comment: @Jsor: The winding looks correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request a depth buffer:

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

And enable depth testing:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you tell me why after adding a depth buffer, it is correct?

Comment: Enabling depth testing without a depth buffer does nothing.  Without depth testings your quads/triangles will be drawn into the framebuffer in the order you send them so later geometry has the chance of overwriting earlier things.